# Replace first Letter in a field Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi Guys I have this Table
[image: My Original table]

I need to replace the First Letter in ACCT_NAME with the First Name of ACCT_SHORT_NAME. Records like the Higliighted(RAFFMAN) should not be changed. I have tried:

```
select acct_name, ACCT_SHORT_NAME,replace(acct_name, substr(acct_name, 1, 1),      ACCT_SHORT_NAME)
 from tbaadm.gam where schm_type = 'TDA' and rcre_user_id  = 'SYSTEM' and substr(acct_name,2,1) = ' '
```

I am getting:

[image: Table after select]

This means that am Picking the whole value in ACCT_SHORT_NAME. WHat is the best way to do what am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract first name by using [INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) function to get the position of  first empty space

```
   replace(acct_name, substr(acct_name, 1, 1),  subst(ACCT_SHORT_NAME,1,INSTR(ACCT_SHORT_NAME,' ')))
```

To Account for short name which have first name only use `CASE`

Comment: See what about where ACCT_NAME is Just One Name like 'MOHAMED' This is Not working